# filter until some condition is met for the first time

Tags: javascript

It's not a real world example, I over-simplified it. Giving this array:

```
const a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,4,5]; // Etc. Random numbers after.
```

I want to filter it to have only those matching a pattern (let's say greater than 3 for this trivial example) until something appends for the first time (let's say element is greater than 7)

So for this example, I just want: `[4,5,6,7]`. But with `filter`, I would have the trailing `4` and `5`:

```
const a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,4,5].filter((v) => v > 3)
// returns: [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 5]
```

So I want to get item from an array and definitively stop after a condition. How can I filter then stop after the first time a condition is not met? (without `for` loop, I want to keep it "functional-like")

```
const a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,4,5,1,2,976,-1].awsome_function();
// returns: [4, 5, 6, 7, 8] because it stopped after the first 8.
```

Comment: "The condition" is "the first time an element is greater than 7". I'm sorry to be unclear (to be fair, I think my whole question is unclear, I don't know how to precise it)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and combine both conditions.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 5],
    result = [];

array.some(a => (a > 3 && result.push(a), a > 7));
console.log(...result);
```

ES5

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 5],
    result = [];

array.some(function (a) {
    if (a > 3) {
        result.push(a);
    }
    return a > 7;
});
console.log(...result);
```

A functional approach with `filter` and two constraints as function and a closure over a boolean value.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 5],
    filterFn = v => v > 3,
    stopFn = v => v > 7,
    filterBy = (fFn, sFn, go = true) => v => go && fFn(v) && (go = !sFn(v)),
    result = array.filter(filterBy(filterFn, stopFn));

console.log(...result);
```

Comment: Can you tell me how does it work? To be honest, I didn't see this way of using `Array#some` yet. Are you passing two arguments inside, or what?

Comment: Ok thanks! I read your code but I don't understand the logic. I know `some` will return a boolean, but the `(a > 3 && result.push(a), a > 7)` part sounds really weird for me (I still have to learn)

Comment: i have added the same in a es5 style, which is better readable. basically it checks if the value is greater than 3 and push the value to the result set, then it returns the check for greater than 7. if `true` then the iteration stops.

Comment: This solution is not very functional. It has a side effect of pushing into `result`. These solutions are more functional [solution](/a/71066312/2602440) and [solution](/a/42628838/2602440).

Comment: @RuiCastro, please have a look to the last approach for filtering without side effects (pure function).

Answer (score 5):

If you want to keep the functional style you can use this :

```
Array.prototype.filterUntil = function(predicate, stop){

  let shouldStop = false;

  return this.filter(function filter(value, index){
    if(stop(value)){
      shouldStop = true;
    }

    return shouldStop && predicate(value);
  });
}
```

In your case you can call it like this :

```
data.filterUntil(value => value > 3, value => value < 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of keeping it functional style is to use `reduce`.

```js
Array.prototype.filterUntil = function(fn, stopFn) {
  const { result } = this.reduce(
    ({ result, isStopped }, item) => {
      isStopped = isStopped || stopFn(item);
      return {
        result: !isStopped && fn(item) ? [...result, item] : result,
        isStopped,
      };
    },
    { result: [], isStopped: false }
  );
  return result;
};

console.log(
  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,4,5].filterUntil(e => e > 3, e => e > 7)
);
```